# Dash download in-memory generated file on button click: How to give filename?

Tags: python-3.x, button, download, filenames, plotly-dash

I generate an *in-memory* Excel file via `pd.ExcelWriter` and `BytesIO` for a click event in my Python3.8 dash app.

Everything works as it should be. When I download my file I get this popup message asking me if I would like to continue to download/open the generated file. However, the popup message shows this (I guess `base64` encoded) string (or path?), e.g. `...ydaHdjhgk328AAAAnxsAA==` and after downloading the download gets a (randomly assigned?) set of characters as the filename (e.g. `ZySzsdn1.xlsx`).

How can I adjust this so it would display and assign the filename to something like `download.xlsx`? My guess is that is has something to do with the `base64` encoded `href`.

The function to generate the excel file:

```
def write_product_file():
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine="xlsxwriter")
    upload_df = pd.DataFrame()
    upload_df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="sheet1")
    writer.save()
    return output
```

The button in my Dash application:

```
html.Div(
  id="select-upload-form",
  style={"width": "100%"},
  children=[
    dbc.Button(
      "Download the upload form",
      id="download-excel",
      color="secondary",
      external_link="true",
      target="",
      href="",
    ),
  ],
),
```

And finally my callback:

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("download-excel", "href"),
        Output("download-excel", "color"),
        Output("download-excel", "target"),
    ],
    [Input("download-excel", "n_clicks")],
)
def download_template_file(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        excelfile = write_product_file()
        excelfile.seek(0)
        media_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        data = base64.b64encode(excelfile.read()).decode("utf-8")
        href_data = f"data:{media_type};base64,{data}"
        return href_data, "success", href_data,
    else:
        return None, "secondary", None
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `Download` component from the dash-extensions package,

```
pip install dash-extensions == 0.0.18
```

The syntax is simpler, and it has a `filename` argument. Here is a small example,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash_extensions import Download
from dash_extensions.snippets import send_bytes

# Generate some example data.
data = np.column_stack((np.arange(10), np.arange(10) * 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a column", "another column"], data=data)
# Create app.
app = dash.Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([html.Button("Download xlsx", id="btn"), Download(id="download")])


@app.callback(Output("download", "data"), [Input("btn", "n_clicks")])
def generate_xlsx(n_nlicks):

    def to_xlsx(bytes_io):
        xslx_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(bytes_io, engine="xlsxwriter")
        df.to_excel(xslx_writer, index=False, sheet_name="sheet1")
        xslx_writer.save()

    return send_bytes(to_xlsx, "some_name.xlsx")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the dash-extensions package.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Hi ehmher, thanks a lot for this extensions! That really helped me a lot. I'm thinking, if my app does need initial callbacks and I don't want to trigger this download callback, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can add prevent_initial_call=True to the callback itself.

Comment: And `bytes_io` is `None`?

Comment: Can you explain why this solution works? send_bytes gets a function that returns None. How does it get the content? I.e. how does it access the xlsx_writer?

Comment: The 'send_bytes' function expects a function handle that writes to a BytesIO object. In the case above, the 'xslx_writer' writes to the BytesIO  object.

Comment: is it possible to get whole webpage, as per example able to download single dataframe in excel??