# Download csv with Flask returning 404 error

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

When I click the download button I am getting

> **404 not found** The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I am using flask to download the dynamically created CSV file

Please see my code below

```
filename = f"{CSV}"
        path = f"downloadable/{filename}"
        data = [titles, prices, sizes, sold]

        data = [list(map(lambda element: element.text, arr)) for arr in data]
        with open(CSV, 'w') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            j = 0
            while j < len(titles):
                row = []
                for i in range(len(data)):
                    row.append(data[i][j])
                writer.writerow(row)
                j += 1
        uri = path

        #df = pd.read_csv(CSV, names=['Title', 'Sold Price', 'Size', 'Sold Date'])
        #df = df.to_csv(CSV)
        return [build_download_button(uri)]
    else:
       raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

@app.server.route('/downloadable/<path:path>')
def serve_static(path):
    root_dir = os.getcwd()
    return flask.send_from_directory(
        os.path.join(root_dir, 'downloadable'), path
    )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # app.run(debug=True)
    app.run_server(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'),
                   port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 1112)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the [`Download` component](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions) instead? The syntax is simpler and it supports larger files. Here is a small example from the docs, that downloads a file from disk,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html  
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash_extensions import Download
from dash_extensions.snippets import send_file

app = dash.Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([html.Button("Download", id="btn"), Download(id="download")])

@app.callback(Output("download", "data"), [Input("btn", "n_clicks")])
def func(n_clicks):
    return send_file("/home/emher/Documents/Untitled.png")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

If is also possible to download the data [without writing to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62088521/2428887) if you prefer.

Comment: The csv is generated dynamically and the download is triggered by an appearing button. For whatever reason I cannot use the '''Download''' button method because the CSV is not within the same directory

Comment: The .csv can be anywhere, it is not limited to the same directory. You could also just send the data directly without writing to disk.

Comment: Do you know how to change the directory so that it can be a github directory? I want to deploy this app with heroku